# Network addressing for multi-Processor Systems

Tags: networking, multiprocessor

I don't get how Network addressing works for Multi-processor systems.

Check me out : 
Normal TCP/IP Networking uses The destination IP to designate the entire host/system, and the L4  (TCP/UDP) destination port to designate the target application.

1. I can (presumably) set the system to have one IP address, and have 
   applications running on the different CPU's use different L4 port numbers.
   Then, for each incoming packet the L4 port can be used to decide to which 
   CPU to send it. BUT - how does the system ensure applications on one CPU 
   will not re-use a L4 Port number being used on the other?
2. If the above is the same, it seems to mean I can't really use two
   (or more) CPU's for one application. For example, if I am running a
   web-server,  all packets toward it will have a TCP port value of 80,
   and how will the  system then decide which packets to send top which
   CPU?
3. It is possible, of course to give each CPU its own IP address - but
   then again, I will not be able to run a multi-CPU application.

What am I missing? how does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Multi-processor systems and networking are independent from each other.

You can have many network namespaces on a single processor system where each namespace will have a different address, but the same processor will execute the code.

You can have a single network address for a multi-processor system, where all network requests will be processed by whatever processor happens to be available to execute the current thread.

If you somehow want to associate certain processors with certain network addresses (or even port numbers of applications), you'll have to set up this on the OS, using `cgroups` etc.

"Give each CPU its own IP address" doesn't exist as a concept. "Have the OS make some sort of partitions, and assign a IP address and a single processor to each partition" works. Like any other combination, i.e. "3 IP addresses, and 2 dedicated processors". Or "use a dedicated processor for this dedicated application that is listening on port 80".